# Change state of components to reflect selected page ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the state or props of child components of a larger component `<Navigation />` in order to reflect what is being displayed on my website.

That's the big picture and I thought it would be really easy but it's not. Here is my code:

```
// This is the parent component 
var Navigation = React.createClass({
    
  getInitialState: function(){
    var endpoints = require("./data/naviEnd.js");
    return {
      endpoints: endpoints
    }             
  },

  renderEndpoints: function(key){
    var endpointDetails = this.state.endpoints[key];
    return(
      <NavEndpt activeRoute={this.props.activeRoute} toggleState={this.toggleState} id={endpointDetails.id} key={endpointDetails.title} url={endpointDetails.url} title={endpointDetails.title}/>
    )
    
  },

  render: function() {
    return(
        <div id="navigation">
            {Object.keys(this.state.endpoints).map(this.renderEndpoints)}
        </div>
    )
  }
});

// this is the child component that renders the div and links contained inside
var NavEndpt = React.createClass({

  handleClick: function() {

  },

  render: function() {

    return(
      <div id={this.props.id}>
        <Link className={this.props.active} onClick={this.handleClick} id={this.props.id + "-link"} to={this.props.url}>{this.props.title}</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

I have been experimenting with a whole bunch of ways to update state and pass information down with props and nothing works. My `<Navigation />` component doesn't have a `this.props.children` and I thought it would since there are two child components `<NavEndpt />`. The React Docs are not very helpful. What can I try next?

Comment: Are you confused by how passing down state as props works? I am a little confused about what your exact problem is.

Comment: I mean I can see that you're passing down an "activeRoute" prop to NavEndpt, but you're trying to use an "active" prop

Comment: @MahmudAdam I know how to pass down state as props, I don't know how to make a click event that updates props or state in order to graphically represent what link is currently active. Like this: I have two links- one link is 'active' and displaying content and the other isn't active and it's content is not being displayed. I want to be able to click the links and change which one is active and displaying, but only one.

Comment: @BenHare yes I have dead code in there I've been at this specific task for hours sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess I'd start by asking why you think Navigation should have this.props.children - I know it has two children, but it isn't passed them as props. It is creating them. It would receive a children props if it was invoked like this:

```
<Navigation>
  <div>This is a child!</div>
</Navigation>
```

The div there would be passed in as a prop called "children".

Now if you're trying to change the state of Navigation and have it pass some of that information down to the NavEndpt, you could set up something like this:

```
var Navigation = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    var endpoints = require("./data/naviEnd.js");
    return {
      endpoints: endpoints
    }             
  },

  changeEndpoints: function() {
    // Get new endpoints somehow
    this.setState({endpoints: newEndpoints});
  }

  render: function() {
    return(
      <div id="navigation">
        <NavEndpt endpoints={this.state.endpoints} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

This would then cause the NavEndpt to receive new props, which are the current endpoints in the Navigation state, whenever they're updated (as I have in my dumb function there that represents some on click or ajax request or whatever that gets new endpoints).

Comment: You're absolutely correct my question is vague and I'm sorry. But I really appreciate your helpful response. I am going to ask a new question that better captures my point and post the link to it in this comment. My hope is that you can help me out when I ask a new, better question. Cheers, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39380367/update-sibling-state-based-on-another-clicked-sibling-reactjs