# Update sibling state based on another clicked sibling ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, jsx

Good afternoon,

I am having trouble changing the state of components which are siblings. Basically they look like this:

```
<Navigation>
  <NavEndpt /> About <--- no
  <NavEndpt /> Blog
  <NavEndpt /> Projects
</Navigation>
```

Each `<NavEndpt />` is a link that routes to a different 'page' or route on my website unless it is the first one listed, "About". About I want to be a drop down/lightbox feature something pretty to show off my CSS knowledge. So when one of the links is clicked I want it to go where I want; additionally, I'd like it to reflect which link is currently "active" (or not) by both changing it's `state.active` to `true` or `false` and adding an additional class `active` for CSS purposes. I want to new "active" class to only be present on a `<NavEndpt />` that's `state.active` is `true`.

Yet everything I have tried so far hasn't worked and I've been at this for two days. I'd appreciate someone who is more experienced with React to show me how to accomplish this.

Here is what I am working with:

```
var MasterLayout = React.createClass({
  mixins: [History],

  render: function(){
      var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
            (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                doSomething: this.doSomething
            })
          );

    return(

        <div id="container">
          <Navigation activeRoute={this.props.location.pathname} />
          <div id="content">
            {childrenWithProps}
          </div>
        </div>
      )

  }
});

var Navigation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      var endpoints = require("./data/naviEnd.js");
      return {
        endpoints: endpoints,
        activeRoute: this.props.activeRoute
      }           
    },
renderEndpoints: function(key){
      var endpointDetails = this.state.endpoints[key];

      return(
        <NavEndpt id={endpointDetails.id} key={endpointDetails.title} url={endpointDetails.url} title={endpointDetails.title}/>
        )

    },

    render: function(){


      return(
          <div id="navigation">
              {Object.keys(this.state.endpoints).map(this.renderEndpoints)}
          </div>
        )
      }
    });

// Created child not a this.props.child of <Navigation /> component 
        // as pointed out by @BenHare

        var NavEndpt = React.createClass({

          handleClick: function(){

            this.setState({
              active: true
            })

          },
          render: function(){

            return (
              <div onClick={this.handleClick} className="navLink" id={this.props.id}>
                <Link id={this.props.id + "-link"} to={this.props.url}>{this.props.title}</Link>
              </div>
              )
          }
        })
```

Currently this only changes creates and set states for each `<NavEndpt />` I tried to make this mess as clean as possible for Stack Overflow.

The best fix I have come up with so far uses a lot of DOM selection and hardcoded if/else statements. It also doesn't light up my "About" component because it doesn't have a `url` property. That's significant because I have the below solution tied up to the `pathname` of my entire layout component.

```
var MasterLayout = React.createClass({
  mixins: [History],

  render: function(){
      var childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
            (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                doSomething: this.doSomething
            })
          );
return(

    <div id="container">
      <Navigation activeRoute={this.props.location.pathname} />
      <div id="content">
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    </div>
  )

}

}); 


  // This is the parent component that sits on the side or the top depending on the
  // broswer size, contains components NavEndpt
  var Navigation = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
      var endpoints = require("./data/naviEnd.js");
      return {
        endpoints: endpoints,
        activeRoute: this.props.activeRoute
      }           
    },
// Always makes the website's initial view the home route
    componentDidMount: function(){
        var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
        var projects = document.getElementById("projects");
        var about = document.getElementById("about");

        var active = this.props.activeRoute

        this.setActive();
    },
// resets the hard coded CSS class
    resetClasses: function(){
      var active = this.props.activeRoute

      var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
      var projects = document.getElementById("projects");
      var about = document.getElementById("about");    

          cover.className = "navLink";
          projects.className = "navLink";
          about.className = "navLink";
    },
// checks pathname of <MasterLayout/>
// also somehow makes it so a refresh does not
// return you to "/"
    setActive: function(){
      var active = this.props.activeRoute

      var cover = document.getElementById("cover");
      var projects = document.getElementById("projects");
      var about = document.getElementById("about");

        if (active === "/"){

        cover.className += " active";
      } else if (active === "/projects"){

        projects.className += " active"
      } else if (active === "/about"){
        about.className += " active"
      }
},
// listens for updates, resets active first and sets it
componentDidUpdate: function(){

  this.resetClasses();
  this.setActive();

},

renderEndpoints: function(key){
  var endpointDetails = this.state.endpoints[key];

  return(
    <NavEndpt id={endpointDetails.id} key={endpointDetails.title} url={endpointDetails.url} title={endpointDetails.title}/>
    )

},

render: function(){


  return(
      <div id="navigation">
          {Object.keys(this.state.endpoints).map(this.renderEndpoints)}
      </div>
    )
  }
});



    var NavEndpt = React.createClass({

      handleClick: function(){

        this.setState({
          active: true
        })

      },
      render: function(){

        return (
          <div onClick={this.handleClick} className="navLink" id={this.props.id}>
            <Link id={this.props.id + "-link"} to={this.props.url}>{this.props.title}</Link>
          </div>
          )
      }
    })
```

Comment: Because of the unidirectional data-flow of React it's hard to communicate state between sibling components without some kind of dedicated state management. Redux is a popular choice https://github.com/reactjs/redux

Comment: @RedMercury thanks for the tip, I was watching [a video series on React.](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b) It eventually branches out into Flux and then Redux, where do you think I should start Flux or Redux? Are they the same? I barely have a decent grasp on regular React sorry for all the questions.

Comment: Go for redux, its more popular and people have been switching to it from flux. Best place I know to start learning redux is this video series by its creator
https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: Yeah now that I see what you're asking I agree with @RedMercury

Comment: @RedMercury wow that's awesome, thanks for the link! Thanks also to Ben Hare.